# SQLite SearchView not filtering data properly

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

Hello Android developers. I am new at Java programming and I faced an issue. I have made a program with SQLite database. It is simple program with add and delete features. Now I want to add search/filter feature and I think about using searchView. I followed tutorial and used this code inside setOnQueryTextListener:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But when I used this code, it filtered elements, but after searching with this method once, I cannot Add any more items to database or delete them from it. I have a listView with names only. Maybe someone knows how to fix this code? Maybe I have to use other code? I need it working... Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: May be the items are added but you can not see them because the list is filtered. Try setting `searchView.setText("")` when you try to add or delete an item.

Comment: I can see items, everything is good, when i filter once i see all the list of names, but i cant add any more items and i cant delete them

Answer (score 0):

I am just answering with what i have understand with your post.

If you want to see the changes after adding or deleting an item you should notify the adapter that the items are modified.It means you have to add this code.

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

lv.setAdapter(adapter);

And if you are using an arraylist to show the data you should clear the arralist also like this.

planlist.clear();

Refer my code for your reference

```
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            planlist.clear();
            planlist = db.getplanlist(newText);
            adapter = new PlansAdapter(PlansActivity.this, planlist);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String newText) {

            return true;
        }
    };
```